# Making URLs more readable

Tags: discussion

One of the most common edits I make is to turn ugly URLs into clean textual references.

For example:

https://www.google.com.au/webhp?ie=UTF-8#safe=off&hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=URL+readability&oq=URL+readability

becomes

[Google search for URL readability](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?ie=UTF-8#safe=off&hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=URL+readability&oq=URL+readability).

While there is debate about how understandable URLs are to modern readers, this to me is a basic part of web-page writing style to keep things readable - it is as important as putting a capital letter at the start of a sentence.

In an attempt to make more people get this right the first time, I propose adding it at the bottom of the current FAQ question on Meta.ELL.SE.

Answers below are proposed texts. Please consider posting your own version, and vote on your favourite.

Comment: Hey Carlo! If you're suggesting we add it to [the actual meta faq page](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/faq), we unfortunately don't have the power to edit that right now. I think we get a shot at it once it's out of beta, but right now mods can only edit the first section of the main site's FAQ page. If you mean to add it somewhere else, please correct me :)

Comment: @Wendi, yes, I meant adding to the actual meta FAQ page, but, sorry, I didn't know that mods cannot edit that page. Any suggestion?

Comment: Carlo, if you edit this post so that, instead of a question, it is an explanation of how and why people should make more readable links (perhaps titled "Please make URLs more readable" and explaining the code behind it for those who don't know) I would be happy to tag this as [tag:featured]. Then it would appear in the Community Bulletin for a while and hopefully gain attention, as we did with [J.R.'s post asking for more detailed questions](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: @WendiKidd Even if the site would not be anymore in beta phase, the only section that moderators can edit is the one titled "What kind of questions can I ask here?" for which suggestions on how to write a post should not be added. Your suggestion of creating a "call to action" question is good; I have seen such questions in other meta sites, and created some of them in the site I moderate.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for the info! I didn't know we could never edit the other sections. Carlo, I'm still up for featuring this post if you want to edit it into an explanation of what to do :)

Comment: @Wendi, thanks. I will edit the question in this weekend :)